# How to post a specific UPnP actions with argument using the upnpx library for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, upnp, upnpx

I managed to successfully identify the UPnP device over WiFi. Upnpx gives easy example in the demo project. But how can I post an action `@"turnDeviceOnOff"` with argument `@"1"` to the `BasicUPnPDevice`?

Comment: Did you get any outcome?